# Print the filename only when found

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

so I have a command that prints the host if found.

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v m="$host" '$2~m {p=1} NF>2 && $2!~m {p=0} p' ${TEMP}/*
```

and this is the result result of it

```
33 VMME87      VMware        51402EC000CF2732 3:0:2
                             51402EC000CF2730 3:0:1
                             51402EC000CF2730 2:0:1
                             51402EC000CF2732 2:0:2
83 VMME87          VMware        51402EC000CF2732 1:2:4
                                 51402EC000CF2730 1:2:3
                                 51402EC000CF2730 0:2:3
                                 51402EC000CF2732 0:2:4
```

However, is it possible to also print the name of the file to where it was found?

Probably something like this:

```
**Name of the file**
33 VMME87      VMware        51402EC000CF2732 3:0:2
                             51402EC000CF2730 3:0:1
                             51402EC000CF2730 2:0:1
                             51402EC000CF2732 2:0:2
echo (space)

**Name of the file**    
83 VMME87          VMware        51402EC000CF2732 1:2:4
                                 51402EC000CF2730 1:2:3
                                 51402EC000CF2730 0:2:3
                                 51402EC000CF2732 0:2:4
```

If i use a `grep`, it prints the name of the file but does not print all the last column.

```
Name of the file 33 VMME87      VMware        51402EC000CF2732 3:0:2
```

Comment: Tell us more about the input files.  Particularly how many columns they have, and what the delimiters are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current filename is available in the `FILENAME` variable. Change this part

```
{p=1}
```

to

```
{p=1; print FILENAME}
```

---

If you want only the filename without the path, use:

```
{p=1;sub(/^.*\//,"",FILENAME);print FILENAME}
```

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl.. works perfectly! However, it includes the complete file path. `/export/sto/temp/GLB-MNL-HP-3PAR-V400`. Is there a way to remove this path and keep just the filename? remove `/export/sto/temp/` and keep `GLB-MNL-HP-3PAR-V400`

Comment: @gafm with awk you could use `{p=1;sub(/^.*\//,"",FILENAME);print FILENAME}`